# owl:hasKey in Protégé

Tags: owl, protege

I would like to use `owl:hasKey` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F9:_Keys) in Protégé. I am quite new to the software and I cannot find it. Can somebody tell me how I achieve this?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: "Target for Key" in the [Class Description view](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/class-description/).

Comment: how. to make hasKey work? it seems it does nothing in Protege after reasoner start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) correctly points out:

> "Target for Key" in the [Class Description view](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/class-description/).